# Col-xs-6 divs with margins always end up stacking

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image: Columns Issue]

The picture shows what I want to render. The col-xs-6 divs are the main issue here; I'm assigning them a background-color to make each col-xs-6 look like a panel which means I also need there to be some visible separation between each col-xs-6.

However, any attempts *at all* to assign margins to the col-xs-6 divs results in them stacking under each other instead of side by side, irrespective of whether I'm testing on mobile or full desktop resolution.

[EDIT: Requested code]

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1" style="padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px">
        <div class="row" data-bind="with: ElementPairs()[2]">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 backgroundPanel fullpad" >
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <!-- Picture -->
                            <img class="img-responsive img-center" src="/Content/images/Land/buttons/button_blankImage.png" style="background: url('/content/images/land/buttons/button1.png') 50% 50% cover no-repeat;">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-9" data-bind="text: Caption">Some Caption here</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 backgroundPanel fullpad">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <!-- Picture -->
                            <img class="img-responsive img-center" src="/Content/images/Land/buttons/button_blankImage.png" style="background: url('/content/images/land/buttons/button2.png') 50% 50% cover no-repeat;">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-9" data-bind="text: Caption">Some other caption here and additional description.</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wrap with a div of class "row", that'll add the margins.

Comment: This would be *much* easier to debug with an example... A code example I mean*

Comment: Use padding instead of margins

Comment: The columns each have a fixed width size and are floating, so if you add a left or right margin, they will be pushed down and become stacked. I think you should but another div inside the column and give that div the margin or padding. Like this: `<div class="col-xs-3"><div style="padding:10px;"></div></div><div class="col-xs-9"><div style="padding:10px;"></div></div>`

Comment: It looks like you have a row directly under another row (lines 3 & 4). Rows can't be children of other rows. You should remove one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, any attempts at all to assign **margins to the col-xs-6 divs**
>   **results in them stacking under each other instead of side by side**,
>   irrespective of whether I'm testing on mobile or full desktop
>   resolution.

This is key for the answer. This is how the columns work in boostrap 3:

- [grid](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins/grid.less)
- [grid-framework](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins/grid-framework.less)

As you can see, when they create grid layout, of 12 columns, they calculate widths in percentages, and corresponding paddings and margins. Every column is floating to the `left` (or `right` for RTL).

If one of the columns becomes wider than "standard" calculated value (in your case you added additional margin), then two div-blocks with of width `col-*-6` are not fitting anymore in one row, and the last one *floats to the left in the next line*, it looks like it was stacked. This is what happening in your case <del>(though, I don't exclude, that you simply messed up with the breakpoints :) - but you haven't provided the code snippet in the question)</del>.

If you need to enlarge margins, you need at the same time to give out the same space from paddings/width of each column, at the same time - playing responsive, and updating corresponding breakpoints. Normally, no one does it manually. It's recommended to use `less` or `sass` mixins to generate the new grid with your new parameters. The topic was well explained [on their official website](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-less.).

p.s. do not forget to wrap each column with `row`, when nesting columns. It's common mistake not to include rows to the layout, they are necessary.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
    <div class="panel panel-success">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Some Title</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Some Body Content Comes here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <p> some footer content of a box comes here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-danger">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Some Title</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Some Body Content Comes here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <p> some footer content of a box comes here</p>
      </div>
    </div></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
    <div class="panel panel-warning">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Some Title</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Some Body Content Comes here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <p> some footer content of a box comes here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Some Title</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Some Body Content Comes here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <p> some footer content of a box comes here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Optional: clear the XS cols if their content doesn't match in height -->
  <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Some Title</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Some Body Content Comes here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <p> some footer content of a box comes here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the Best and simplest way of using bootstrap as boxes (panels as boxes).

Answer (score -1):

The Bootstrap grid system requires col-* elements to be wrapped with "row": http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
  <!-- Optional: clear the XS cols if their content doesn't match in height -->
  <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
</div>
```